# Cadastro com Jquery com erro

Tags: php, jquery

olha eu aqui de novo, eu custo a vir aqui, mas quando eu chego no meu limite, sou obrigado, preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, eu estou tentando fazer um cadastro com JQUERY e PHP, porém ele sempre da cadastro efetuado com sucesso, mesmo com todo o cadastro em branco. Vejam os códigos:

PHP

```
  if((isset($_POST['username'])) && (isset($_POST['password']))){


if( trim($_POST['username']) == '' ){
  echo ('É obrigatório digitar seu usuário');
   exit();
}
  elseif( empty($_POST['password'] ) ) {
 echo ('É obrigatório digitar sua senha');

 exit();
}

if(!preg_match("/^([a-z-0-9 ]+)$/i",$_POST['username'])) {
    echo "só letras e números!";

    exit();
}

 elseif( empty($_POST['password']) ) {
 echo ('É obrigatório digitar sua senha');

 exit();
}

 elseif( empty($_POST['email'] ) ) {
 echo ('É obrigatório digitar seu e-mail');

 exit();
}

     elseif( empty( $_POST['nome'] ) ) {
 echo ('É obrigatório digitar seu nome');

 exit();
}

     elseif( empty( $_POST['sobrenome'] ) ) {
 echo ('É obrigatório digitar seu sobrenome');

 exit();
}


 $username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM usuarios WHERE username=?        LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
  $stmt->store_result();

 if($stmt->num_rows > 0)  //To check if the row exists
  {
       echo "esse usuário já existe";

  exit();
  }

  $username = strtolower($_POST['username']); 
$username =  str_replace(" ","",$username);

 $query = "insert into usuarios(nome, sobrenome, username, email, nomecompleto, password) values ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nome']) ."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sobrenome']) ."', '". trim($username) ."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']) ."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nome']) ." ". mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sobrenome']) ."', '".   md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password'])) ."')";
$rs = $mysqli->query($query);


echo "1";


}
```

JQUERY

```
  $(function($) {

$('#formcad').submit(function() {

    // Limpando mensagem de erro
     $("#resposta").html('');


    // Enviando informações do formulário via AJAX
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

        // Se não retornado nenhum erro
        if (!resposta)
            // Redirecionando para o painel
            window.location.href = 'cad.php';

             $("#resposta").html(resposta); 
           if(resposta === 1){


  }else{

 $('#nome').val("");
 $('#sobrenome').val("");
 $('#password').val("");
  $('#username').val("");
  $('#email').val("");
  $("#resposta").html("Você foi cadastrado com sucesso!");

  }




    });

    // Retornando false para que o formulário não envie as informações da forma convencional
    return false;

});
 });
```

Comment: Sabes como formatar o código em cima? Acho que vai ser mais claro para todos se estiver formatado, assim por exemplo: https://codepaste.net/9ycwwq

Comment: coloca o console.log em cada if pra ir debugando linha a linha

Comment: Duas possibilidades: 1) O problema é no ajaxSubmit(). Verifique o que você está recebendo no valor "resposta".

2) Geralmente chamadas AJAX levam em consideração o código de retorno HTTP que você recebe de volta na chamada (na casa dos 200 são status de sucesso; 400 são erros do cliente; dentre outros). E essa é mais uma possibilidade de ser o problema. Nesse caso, além de dar "echo 'MENSAGEM_DE_ERRO';", você precisaria definir um cabeçalho de resposta do PHP (usando a função header), pra especificar o erro.

Comment: Seu php retorna as mensagens, faltou isso, faltou aquilo, e o seu jquery diz "cadastrado com sucesso" quando a resposta for diferente de 1, logo esta "tudo certo" aparentemente...

Comment: é mais não funciona

Comment: note as aspas no meu "tudo certo", você esta dizendo que é pra dar cadastrado com sucesso quando a mensagem vem diferente de 1, ou seja se vier 'É obrigatório digitar seu usuário' vai dar cadastrado com sucesso. tenha mais atenção com as logicas dos IFs para ter menos problemas...

Answer (score 1):

Você tem um pequeno erro de logica no IF que faz a verificação da resposta, tente com a seguinte modificação:

```
 $(function($) {

$('#formcad').submit(function() {

    // Limpando mensagem de erro
     $("#resposta").html('');


    // Enviando informações do formulário via AJAX
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(resposta) {

        // Se não retornado nenhum erro
        if (!resposta)
            // Redirecionando para o painel
            window.location.href = 'cad.php';

           if(resposta == '1'){

 $('#nome').val("");
 $('#sobrenome').val("");
 $('#password').val("");
  $('#username').val("");
  $('#email').val("");
  $("#resposta").html("Você foi cadastrado com sucesso!");

  }else{

             $("#resposta").html(resposta); 

  }




    });

    // Retornando false para que o formulário não envie as informações da forma convencional
    return false;

});
 });
```